# Does aminosugars give positive response in alkaloid tests?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, biochemistry

Does aminosugars give positive response to [test for alkaloids](http://thepharmacistpharma.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-distinguish-alkaloids.html) such as tests with Dragendorff's reagent, mayer's reagent, Hager's reagent, Wagner's reagent etc?

Comment: Dragendorff's reagent works for tertiary amines (and some secondary), amino sugars contain primary amines so there is no reaction nor do N-acetylaminosugars

Comment: I saw "aminosugars" but read it as "aminosugaris" and was thinking I don't recognize that dinosaur name, and what's it have to do with alkaloids?  Too much with the kids I guess :)

Comment: @CrossRoads I dont know about any such Aminosaurus :P :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most alkaloids are tertiary amines. Almost all tests for alkaloids, reagents of which are  are solutions of the salts of heavy metals, are precipitation tests. For example, all of tests with Dragendorff's reagent, Mayer's reagent, Hager's reagent, and Wagner's reagent give color precipitates: The heavy metal atom in the reagent with the nitrogen in the alkaloid would form ion pairs. These ion pairs form an insoluble precipitate. The color of the precipitate depends on reagent, plant species, etc. (Ref.1). Most amino sugars are either primary amines or acetamides, thus, I doubt they'd give precipitates with sought reagents. However, some reagents give false-positive tests for non-nitrogenous extracts indicating the presence of alkaloids. The best example is Dragendorff's spray reagent (Ref.2).

Mean time, some reagents are giving negative results even with alkaloid extracts, *e.g.*, Mayer's reagent (Ref.3). Therefore, my answer is purely opinion based.

**References:**

1. Felix G. Coe, Gregory J. Anderson, "Screening of medicinal plants used by the Garífuna of Eastern Nicaragua for bioactive compounds," *Journal of Ethnopharmacology* **1996**, *53(1)*, 29-50 (https://doi.org/10.1016/0378-8741(96)01424-9).
2. Abdel‐Azim M. Habib, "False‐positive alkaloid reactions," *Journal of Pharmaceutical Sciences* **1980**, *69(1)*, 37-43 (https://doi.org/10.1002/jps.2600690111).
3. J. W. Field, M. Kandiah, "A note on the use of mayer's reagent for the detection of quinine in alkaline urine," *Transactions of the Royal Society of Tropical Medicine and Hygiene* **1935**, *28(4)*, 385-390 (https://doi.org/10.1016/S0035-9203(35)90133-X).

Comment: If I get scope to do this simple lab tests I'll publish it as answer. Currently aminosugars are not available to me. We have chitin flakes though, that makes technically a different question because chitin is polysaccharide.